# Does $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(1, 1)} \frac{\tan(y-1)\sin^2(x-y)}{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

thats the original problem:
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(1, 1)} \frac{\tan(y-1)\sin^2(x-y)}{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}$$

I changed it to this :
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0, 0)} \frac{\tan(y)\sin^2(x-y)}{(x)^2+(y)^2}$$

Since there's $x^2+y^2$ I tried using $x=r\cos(\theta),y=r\sin(\theta)$ but failed.

I'm not even sure if it diverge or converge , and what are the steps to encounter this kind of questions?

Comment: Is there a typo? Or is $y \to 1$?

Comment: yah , changed it thanks

Comment: Try converting the square into a double angle term and then using small angle approximation to eliminate the trig terms

Comment: Try x= 1+Rcos(theta  y=1+ Rsin(theta)

Comment: A very similar question with an answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728016/two-multivariable-limits-help?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Notice first that
$$\tag{1}
\forall x,y\in\mathbb R\;\;
(x+y)^2\ge0 \;\Rightarrow \; x^2+2xy+y^2\ge0
\; \Rightarrow \; -2xy\le x^2+y^2
$$
and
$\forall x\in\mathbb R\;\sin^2x\le x^2.$
Then $\forall x,y\in\mathbb R:\; x^2+y^2\ne0$
$$
0\le\frac{\sin^2(x-y)}{x^2+y^2}\le
\frac{(x-y)^2}{x^2+y^2}=
\frac{x^2-2xy+y^2}{x^2+y^2}
=1+\frac{-2xy}{x^2+y^2}\le 2.
$$
Thus,
$$
\left|\tan y\cdot\frac{\sin^2(x-y)}{x^2+y^2}\right|=
|\tan y|\cdot \frac{\sin^2(x-y)}{x^2+y^2}\
\le 2|\tan y|
$$
and
$$
-2|\tan y|\le \tan y\cdot\frac{\sin^2(x-y)}{x^2+y^2}\le 2|\tan y|.
$$
But
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(-2|\tan y|)=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}2|\tan y|=0,
$$
which completes the proof.

Answer (score 2):

To follow your way using $x=r\cos t, y = r \sin t$, a good idea is to rewrite the expression in a way, so that you can use known standard limits in one variable.

Here the standard limits $\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\sin u}{u}=1$ and $\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\tan u}{u}=1$ are helpful. Excluding the cases $\sin t = 0$ and $\sin t= \cos t$ where the expression evaluates anyways to $0$ you get

$$\frac{\tan(y)\cdot \sin^2(x-y)}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{\tan(r\sin t)\sin^2(r(\cos t -  \sin t))}{r^2}$$
$$= \underbrace{\frac{\tan(r\sin t)\sin^2(r(\cos t -  \sin t))}{r\sin t\cdot r^2(\cos t -  \sin t)^2}}_{\stackrel{r \to 0}{\longrightarrow}1}\cdot r\sin t \cdot (\cos t -  \sin t)^2 \stackrel{r \to 0}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use (partial) Taylor series expansion to get an answer. We know that both $\tan$ and $\sin$ are odd, smooth functions. Hence we can write 
$\sin(x)=x\cdot f(x)$ and $\tan(x)=x\cdot g(x)$, where both $f$ and $g$ are smooth and furtheron we can check that both $f(0)\neq 0$ and $g(0)\neq 0$.
Having this you can do the following:

1. Check that $\sin^2$ has a similar expansion. (Note that this one is even.)
2. Change the coordinates the way you tried to do.
3. Translate the limit $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$ correctly into the new coordinates. (Hint: Just $r\rightarrow 0$ is not enough.)

This method works in a lot of calculations, if, for instance, you have to calculate the limit where the both the nominater and denominater vanish (or diverge to infinity) or if you have to calculate the rate of growth of a difference of two functions approaching $x=0$ or $x=\infty$ resp.